# Transform dictionary object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This dict structure :

```py
data = {
    'a': { 'category': ['c', 'd'] },
    'b': { 'category': ['c', 'd'] }
}
```

should become this dict structure:

```py
data = {
    'c' : ['a', 'b'],
    'd' : ['a', 'b']
}
```

I have following approach:

```py
for key, value in data.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        if 'category' in value:
            for cat in value['category']:
                if cat in categories:
                    categories[cat].append(key)
                else:
                    categories[cat] = [key]
```

I want to know if there is any way to simplify my approach. I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if 'category' in value:
```

This line makes sure that the key `category` is in the dictionary, before using it. Then you get the value from the dictionary corresponding to `category` and iterate it. You can simplify this with `dict.get` method, which would return a default value, if the key is not there in the dictionary. So you can do something like this

```
for cat in value.get('category', []):
```

If the `category` doesn't exist in the dictionary, then an empty list is returned and the loop will have nothing to iterate.

---

Similarly, you are checking if the key exists in the `categories` dictionary, if not, setting a default value (which is a list). You can avoid that `if...else` also, with `dict.setdefault`, like this

```
categories = {}
for key, value in data.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for cat in value.get('category', []):
            categories.setdefault(cat, []).append(key)
```

`dict.setdefault` is similar to `dict.get`, except that it sets the default value against the key and returns the value corresponding to the key.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it with a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), iterating over the categories and appending keys:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, value in data.items():
...     for item in value['category']:
...         d[item].append(key)
... 
>>> dict(d)
{'c': ['a', 'b'], 'd': ['a', 'b']}
```

Comment: Additional import :(

Comment: @Skeec so? It leads to a much more readable implementation. Besides, it's a built-in, it always is available.